# Why would CTreeCtrl DeleteItem fail without an error?

Tags: windows, winapi, mfc

Windows 7
VS 2012, C++

I am debugging a huge program (so no way to trace all possible paths).  After putting some asserts in strategic places, I get that MFC DeleteItem() fails (returns 0) but there is no error (GetLastError() == 0).

This is not directly the problem I am debugging, but I am hoping to get clues from this error as to where to look next.  Without any error and nothing on the web (including MSDN) the only clue (and it might be wrong) is that it is passed a wrong HTREEITEM value, but then why no error?

Comment: If the `DeleteItem` fails this almost always means (IMO) that the item does not exist. Try inserting a `GetItem` beforehand to verify the existence.

Answer (score 2):

The return value of GetLastError() is only meaningful when the documentation tells you it is, generally under the "Return Value" section.

In this case, it is not applicable. The [`CTreeCtrl::DeleteItem` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdhxwhcx.aspx) simply returns `FALSE` (0) if it fails, or non-zero if it succeeds. It is simply returning the result of a [`TVM_DELETEITEM` message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773560.aspx), which the framework sent to the TreeView control on your behalf.

It is up to you to debug *why* deleting the item is failing. Like you mention in the question, the most likely explanation is that the `HTREEITEM` handle specified is invalid. Debugging this shouldn't be difficult. Set a breakpoint in the code on the call to `DeleteItem`, then run the program and simulate the error. When execution reaches the call to `DeleteItem`, the debugger will break in and you can investigate the value of the `HTREEITEM` you're about to pass in. You can also change the value to something known to be valid, like `NULL` (which deletes all the items in the TreeView), just to make sure that you've correctly pinpointed the culprit.

Comment: The DeleteItem is actually defined as a SendMessage(TVM_DELETEITEM), and the doc for SendMessage has this line which confused me:  "When a message is blocked by UIPI the last error, retrieved with GetLastError, is set to 5 (access denied)."

Comment: @Frigg Yes, that is what I said. Okay, so you know that the problem is not UIPI. That was never really a likely explanation. Your process owns the TreeView. A good explanation of UIPI is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625963.aspx).

Comment: What I meant by my comment is that I had assumed that if the function used the LastError at all, it would use it for all errors, not just a particular one (or a few chosen ones).